# C++11 default template argument before variadic pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Why template class argument after argument with default value, but before variadic must have default value too?
[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17ee965639e4d467)

```
template<class A = int, class B, class ...Args>     // B must have default argument
struct Dat{};
```

From another hand, if `A` have no default argument, all ok:

```
template<class A, class B, class ...Args>         // B must have default argument
struct Dat{};
```

Comment: you cannot have non-default parameters after default parameters. It's a language sintax

Comment: Default arguments are useful to *not* explicitly pass an argument for one parameter. For example `template<class A, class B = int> struct X{}; X<double> /* == X<double, int> */`. The arguments are used to fill the parameters always in the same order, so there is no way to use a default argument if you need to pass an argument for the next parameter -- you would need to pass an argument for both parameters.

Comment: The variadic template parameters have nothing to do with it ([see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4052ef994b6203cb)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with variadic templates:

```
template<class First, class Second> struct X {};

X<int, double> // instantiates X with First == int, Second == double
```

The arguments `int` and `double` are used to fill the parameters `First`, `Second` from left to right. The first argument specifies the first parameter, the second argument specifies the second parameter. When a parameter has a default value, you do not need to specify an argument:

```
template<class First, class Second = double> struct X {};

X<int> // instantiates X with First == int, Second == double
```

If you now had a third parameter without a default argument, you could not make use of the default argument:

```
template<class First, class Second = double, class Third> struct X {};

X<int, char> // tries to instantiate X with First == int, Second == char,
             // Third == ??
```

---

A template parameter pack can be empty, so it can follow a parameter with a default argument:

```
template<class First, class Second = double, class... Pack> struct X {};

X<int> // instantiates X with First == int, Second == double, Pack == (empty)
X<int, char> // First == int, Second == char, Pack == (empty)
X<int, char, short, bool> // First == int, Second == char, Pack == {short, bool}
```

---

In the OP's example:

```
template<class A = int, class B, class ...Args> struct Dat {};
         ^~~~~~~        ^~~~~~~  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
         |              |        |no argument required
         |              |an argument IS required
         |no argument required
```

So you always have to provide an argument for the second parameter, therefore, you need to provide an argument for the *first* parameter, too. The default argument for the first parameter cannot be used.